# Security Reasons PHP

Tags: php, security, url

After a successfull login, the user will be send to the page that correspondens to him. So I made that with an `header('Location: URL?id=$id)`

What can I do that the ID will be hidden in the url. So that the user can't change the ID ont the URL? For example I'm logged in as a normal User with my id from the database 63 so un the url is display, *page.php?id=63*

Now when the user changes the id to 64, he will se the page from the user with the id 64. Due security reason I will change that before to make the site online.

How can I hidden the id in the URL by sending the user with an `header('Location:')`

Thank you guys !

Comment: use sessions instead. after successful login, store the user ID in a session variable and read it where you need to figure out the authenticated user.

Comment: Does my answer work?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stroing the id in the URL, you can store it in a session variable.

You can start a session by using the following:

```
session_start();
```

And you can assign session variables using:

```
$id = x; #id taken from database. change x to the database variable
$_SESSION["id"] = $id;
```

Replace *123* with the database user id variable.

Also add `session_start()` to pages where you would want to use the `$_SESSION` variable.